# How can I get all strings starting with [ and ending with ] out of a single line using Python?

Tags: python

Sorry I am very new to python and trying to figure out how to take out a specific string sequence out of all the string

I tried using re but I don't quite get it..

```
import re

userinput = input('Enter the name of the file:')
file = open(userinput)
info = file.readlines()
info = re.sub(r'\[[.+]\]','',info)
print(info)
file.close()
```

if file includes:
notokay[okay]notokayas[okay2]sjnfksdnfnslk

I want to be able to extract:
okay, okay2

Comment: In this case, use `read()`, not `readlines()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following pattern matching for that:

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

Comment: Last character as in the last character of the line? Can you please give an example?

Answer (score 2):

Use `re.findall`

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = "notokay[okay]notokayas[okay2]sjnfksdnfnslk"
print(re.findall(r"\[(.*?)\]", s))
```

**Output:**

```
['okay', 'okay2']
```